# При чтении xml файла в методе @Asynk Spring Boot Чтение файла происходит со второго вызова метода

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, completablefuture

Вызываю метод `importToDB` из контроллера:

```java
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> importToDB(final MultipartFile file, int num) {
    System.out.println("Выполняем в потоке: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "num = " + num);
    numOfTask.put(num, "IN PROGRESS");
    Workbook workbook;
    try {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        numOfTask.put(num, "ERROR");
        System.out.println(exception);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("Ошибка открытия файла" + file.getName() + " thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
   }
   Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
   // .....
}
```

После запуска  Spring Boot приложения первое обращение к этому методу вываливается на IOException:

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Leonid\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8080.86797283140162075\work\Tomcat\ локальный\ROOT\upload_c86caecb_7a98_472b_8ebb_c6342c71c40a_00000000.tmp

Последующие вызовы метода отрабатывают без ошибок. В чем может быть проблема? Может, я что-то упустил.

Comment: Я не на 100% уверен, но думаю дело не в первом вызове, да и вообще не в порядке вызовов. Объект `file` живёт только пока жив  ХТТП запрос. Метод `importToDB` выполняется асинхронно, поэтому запрос может быть прибит до того, как файл вычитали. Я бы посоветовал вычитать файл из ХТТП запроса синхронно (`file.transferTo(...)`), а потом потом вычитанный на диск файл отдать в асинхронный обработчик.

Comment: Решил тем, что передаю из контроллера в сервис InputStream. (file.getInputStream()).

Answer (score 1):

Решил тем, что передаю из контроллера в сервис InputStream (MultipartFile.getInputStream()).

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> importToDB(InputStream inputStream, int num){
    //.....
}
```